# Redirect user to Teams join url with selected account

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We have an integration via API for creating meetings. Our integration uses the API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). This meeting is scheduled by an organizer and we do not send the list of participants. Meetings are created within a tenant, so only users in the tenant's domain can join without waiting for the organizer to accept.

To join, the user clicks a button and the user is redirected to the meeting URL (joinURL - EX: https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/19%3ameeting_M2IzYzczNTItYmY3OC00MDlmLWJjMzUtYmFiMjNlOTY4MGEz%40thread.skype/0?context=%7b%22Tid%22%3a%2272f988bf-87cd011db47%22%2c%22Oid%22%3a%22550fae72-d251-43ec-868c-373732c2704f%22%7d).

After this click, we are experiencing some user experience issues for users who are not authenticated or who have two connected accounts.

After redirecting to the URL, the user is prompted for the ingress format. Image (https://ibb.co/Wfdp42n).  The user chooses the option to continue in the browser. It is then redirected to the anonymous access screen, image (https://ibb.co/WztCVJR).  Naturally, the user types the name and then waits for the organizer to accept. In this scenario, the user has two connected accounts, picture (https://ibb.co/5LGbdH9). In the Teams redirect, we noticed that the URL generates the error "AADSTS16000 - SelectUserAccount", but the user is not redirected to the account selection.

We'd like to know if there's anything we can add to the flow or API parameters to force the user to select their account based on the tenant domain.

Attempts:

Add the domain_hint or email in the joinURL.
Generate an authenticated joinURL.
Force profile selection on link click

Comment: This error typically occurs when there are multiple accounts associated with the user's email address. 
- When the "AADSTS16000 - SelectUserAccount" error occurs, the user should click on the "View and accept" button in the consent dialog box.
- The user will then be redirected to the Azure AD permission consent view, where they can see all the permissions requested by the app. They can review the permissions and click on the "Accept" button to continue with the authentication flow.
- After accepting the permissions, the user will be redirected back to the app.